# Сложение чисел в фиксированном размере бит

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно реализовать сложение двух чисел с фиксированным кол-вом бит(в случае переполнения старшие биты отбрасываются):

Пример: 4 - кол-во бит;  7 и 10 числа для сложения

На выходе получается 1

Думаю, это через побитовые операторы можно сделать, но не понимаю как

Comment: `На выходе получается 1` - число 8 представимо четырьмя битами: `1000`. Как вы получили `1`?

Comment: Уже исправил, входные числа были 7 и 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def f(a, b, n):
    x = -1 if a + b < 0 else 1
    return abs(a + b) % 2 ** (n - 1) * x
```

Comment: Хотел посмотреть на младший бит, передав `n == 1`, но ваша функция всегда возвращает ноль. Подставил данные из вопроса `a == 7, b == 1, n == 4`, в надежде получить единицу (именно этого хочет автор вопроса), но она снова вернула ноль. Что вообще делает ваша функция?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл один из битов отвечает за знак числа. 7 + 1 == 8 в двоичном это `1000`, 4 - 1 == 3, значит надо у числа оставить три бита получаем `000`

Comment: Если знаковый бит вы отбрасываете, то почему для `a == -7, b == 0, n == 4` ваша функция возвращает `-7`, а не `1`?